# Find out p-value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

The average order rate (Orders with revenue > 0) is 58% in the population. How likely is it that the observed sample order rate or greater is because of random chance? I am not able to upload data set here, however, there is a column (named order) having (0 and 1) values.

The order rate is based on a variable that has 1/0 values. We want to compare the order rate of sample vs the order rate in the population and then to find out the likelihood of seeing the sample order rate simply because of randomness.

How to find out p-value?

Comment: A lot of statistical terms are mixed up here with seemingly erroneous interpretations. Could you explain your problem in layman terms? What is your goal with this exercise/test/experiment?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a two-sided, one-sample proportion test on some summary statistics. Here's how one would do this in R (you will need to change 65 and 100 to reflect your data).

Suppose you saw 65 orders with revenue out of 100 total. This test is just one line of code:

```
> prop.test(65, 100, p = 0.58, alternative = "two.sided", conf.level = 0.95, correct = FALSE)

    1-sample proportions test without continuity correction

data:  65 out of 100, null probability 0.58
X-squared = 2.0115, df = 1, p-value = 0.1561
alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to 0.58
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.5525444 0.7363575
sample estimates:
   p 
0.65
```

If the true population rate was really 0.58, then the probability of seeing something this extreme is 15.61% (the p-value above), which is still quite likely by conventional standards. Thus you cannot reject the null hypothesis that this sample came from a distribution with a baseline rate of 0.58. Or to put it slightly differently, this data is consistent with the sample being from that 0.58 baseline distribution. If you observed 68 or 48 instead of 65, then you could be more certain that this sample was unusual.